# What did Godric Gryffindor have a sword for, anyway?

Tags: harry-potter

Why did Godric Gryffindor have a sword made for himself in the first place?

In the series, the only example of a wizard using muggle weaponry I can think of is Bellatrix Lestrange and her knife - being an evil sadist, she would probably enjoy using one against helpless victims because it's more gruesome than the relatively clean (if more painful) *crucio* curse. I can see why she'd use a knife.

The valiant Gryffindor wouldn't want to cut someone up, so why did he ever acquire a sword (and an expensive goblin-made one, too) instead of relying on magic for self-defense? Did he predict its usefulness to the future generations, or was it just meant to be an accessory, or what?

Comment: As Hermione conclusively demonstrated on Ferretface, sometimes the fist is mightier than the wand

Comment: Swords are good for decapitating snakes.

Comment: He used the sword to fight the sea monsters in the Hogwarts lake before he's become an animagus.

Comment: "Who needs wands when you got swag?" (Gryffindor, 982)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The [*Sword of Gryffindor* entry on Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-sword-of-gryffindor)  explicitly answers this question:

> *The question of why a wizard would need a sword, though often asked,
>   is easily answered. **In the days before the International Statute of
>   Secrecy, when wizards mingled freely with Muggles, they would use
>   swords to defend themselves just as often as wands.** Indeed, **it was
>   considered unsporting to use a wand against a Muggle sword** (which is
>   not to say it was never done). Many gifted wizards were also
>   accomplished duellists in the conventional sense, Gryffindor among
>   them.*

Since this was written by JKR herself, we can accept this as a canon answer.

Comment: Nice answer! I was thinking of this bit from Pottermore when I saw the question -- that'll teach me to leave my computer! :)

Comment: @Slytherincess That'll teach you to think that you can be faster than Richard, who incidentally operates at the speed of Thor.

Comment: @Mooz - Whoever is worthy shall possess the power of Richard!

Comment: Great answer. Isn't it also that there are dangers that are strongly magic resistant, which might be more vulnerable to a simple magical sword? Trolls and unicorns come to mind.

Comment: @Luaan, I thought of that, but Gryffindor was among the mightiest wizards of his time so I assume he, if necessary, could still MacGyver his way around them using magic.

Comment: @luann - note also that it is an enchanted sword.